# Bigquery Stream Benchmark

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery officially becomes our device log data repository and live monitor/analysis/diagnostic base. As one step further, We need to measure and monitor data streaming performance. Any relevant benchmark you are using for Bigquery live stream? What relevant once I can refer to?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2):

Since streaming has a limited payload size, see [Quota policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) it's easier to talk about times and other side effects.

We measure between 1200-2500 ms for each streaming request, and this was consistent over the last month as you can see in the chart.

[image]

We seen several side effects although:

- the request randomly fails with type 'Backend error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'Connection error'
- the request randomly fails with type 'timeout'
- some other error messages are non descriptive, and they are so vague that they don't help you, just retry.
- we see hundreds of such failures each day, so they are pretty much constant, and not related to Cloud health.

For all these we opened cases in paid Google Enterprise Support, but unfortunately they didn't resolved it. It seams the recommended option to take for these is an exponential-backoff with retry, even the support told to do so. Which personally doesn't make me happy.

**UPDATE**

Someone requested in the comments new stats, so I posted 2017. It's still the same, there was some heavy data reorganization for us, you see the spike, but essentially it's the same it's around 2sec if you use the max of the streaming insert.

[image]

Comment: We've been seeing the same fails too.  I'm interested in how to measure the performance of streaming so that it can shed a light on our resource planning, including CPU, memory, network and error handling mechanism, which means when new type of data needed to be streamed in, we can estimate if we need upgrade our facilities. On the other hand, if there's a benchmark, we basically can monitor the stream performance and trigger alarms accordingly.

Comment: Do you have a queue before the streaming, or what is the source before streaming, as if that is a queue or a waiting pool, there you can setup the alarm, if it's increasing.

Comment: yes, I have a double queue, one for new data and one for failed ones waiting for retry. That's a doable idea, thank you. In the meanwhile, I use log4j to record fails in files but log files just hard to do any stats on fails from those files. Do you have any idea about record stream logs into somewhere handy for stats?

Comment: we use statsd/graphite charts, it looks the same as I included it has success/fails counts only. We don't keep separate queue for retry, failed ones go directly to the end of the queue.

Comment: @foxwendy I added a new chart, still the same.

Comment: what was the per request size here in your chart?

Comment: @foxwendy close to the maximum of what the API permits, 10MB https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas